# SVN move directories, not losing history

Tags: java, maven, svn, ant

We have the plan to change our modularized application at work from *Ant* to *Maven*. The requirements to that process would be:

- my colleagues can go on working without being involved in that task
- not losing any SVN history
- merge the whole task at once into trunk

Could someone confirm this procedure?

1. create a branch in SVN
2. create new directories in `src` the maven style `src/main/java` and add it to SVN
3. move all source files with SVN, something like `svn mv src/mypackages src/main/java/mypackages`
4. create the pom.xml, ect.
5. merge changes from colleagues to my branch
6. at the end, merge my branch back to trunk

Thanks!

Comment: It looks all right. I've done this several times in the past. Step 4 is the most time consuming though :D

Comment: Be ready to a lot of headache on step 5

Comment: I just tested it and, yes, step 5 would be lots of manual work: that's a _no go_. But I was successfully merging a branch with _git_ keeping _git master_ in sync with _svn trunk_.